# Python error. FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, file, directory

Running a python code but getting a weird error in regards to finding the working directory and file to run the script. `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:` Please let me know if you have any suggestions or know how I may be able to fix the error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: show us the code and a full stack trace

Comment: We need to see the code.

Comment: The file or directory doesn't exist. You need to make it exist.

Comment: yes, I think you are missing a "\" symbol in your folder path. Try use the inline code to outline problem and put more details in the question, so people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a "\" to the end of your folder path.

`folder_path = 'T:\04. Testing\3. Wear Testing\TESTS\CKUW\180604 OP STRAPLESS\Survey Response Data\`

Comment: You would join them using [**`os.path.join`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Comment: OP is not using `os.path.join` but simply concatenating two strings, thus missing a back slash

Comment: @A.B. yes, but using `os.path.join` is the correct way to do it.